# App Crashes on Launch with AutoVerify Enabled in IntentFilter for Deep Linking in .NET 7 Release Build

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm developing an Android app using .NET 7 (with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.2) and have encountered an issue where the app crashes immediately upon launch in the release build when I include the AutoVerify = true attribute in my IntentFilter configuration for deep linking. My intent filter is designed to handle HTTPS URLs for a specific domain and path prefix. Here's the configuration:

```
[Activity(Label = "example", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[]
    {
        Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    },
    DataScheme = "https",
    DataHost = "example.com",
    DataPathPrefix = "/app/",
    AutoVerify = true
)]
```

I've confirmed the assetlinks.json file is correctly placed at /.well-known/assetlinks.json and includes the accurate SHA-256 certificate fingerprints for the app.

The crash occurs only in the release build. Unfortunately, the logs do not provide clear information about the crash's cause (not to me at least :)). Has anyone faced a similar issue or can you explain why enabling AutoVerify might lead to a crash on app launch in a release build? Any advice on troubleshooting or fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
02-28 18:34:26.635  pixel_5_-_api_34    Error   21325   DEBUG   backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000061610  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+192) (BuildId: fa337969c798946280caa45e2d71a2e7)
      #01 pc 000000000003fc99  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmono-android.release.so (offset 0xa16000) (xamarin::android::internal::MonodroidRuntime::mono_log_handler(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, void*)+105) (BuildId: 10717b29f55fb71204c9a80db52d4ca396c33c61)
      #02 pc 00000000003324ca  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (offset 0xa73000) (BuildId: fcb4e1bfd835f76e63a7fb6f3b76e41c25b1c9bb)
      #03 pc 0000000000332654  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (offset 0xa73000) (BuildId: fcb4e1bfd835f76e63a7fb6f3b76e41c25b1c9bb)
      #04 pc 0000000000332696  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (offset 0xa73000) (BuildId: fcb4e1bfd835f76e63a7fb6f3b76e41c25b1c9bb)
      #05 pc 0000000000100f65  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (offset 0xa73000) (BuildId: fcb4e1bfd835f76e63a7fb6f3b76e41c25b1c9bb)
      #06 pc 00000000001360fd  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (offset 0xa73000) (mono_method_get_unmanaged_callers_only_ftnptr+61) (BuildId: fcb4e1bfd835f76e63a7fb6f3b76e41c25b1c9bb)
      #07 pc 00000000000286ca  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmono-android.release.so (offset 0xa16000) (xamarin::android::internal::MonodroidRuntime::init_android_runtime(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*)+1498) (BuildId: 10717b29f55fb71204c9a80db52d4ca396c33c61)
      #08 pc 000000000002a632  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmono-android.release.so (offset 0xa16000) (xamarin::android::internal::MonodroidRuntime::create_and_initialize_domain(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, xamarin::android::jstring_array_wrapper&, xamarin::android::jstring_array_wrapper&, _jobjectArray*, xamarin::android::jstring_array_wrapper&, _jobject*, bool, bool, bool)+146) (BuildId: 10717b29f55fb71204c9a80db52d4ca396c33c61)
      #09 pc 000000000002e63a  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmono-android.release.so (offset 0xa16000) (xamarin::android::internal::MonodroidRuntime::Java_mono_android_Runtime_initInternal(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobjectArray*, _jstring*, _jobjectArray*, int, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, int, unsigned char, unsigned char)+5274) (BuildId: 10717b29f55fb71204c9a80db52d4ca396c33c61)
      #10 pc 0000000000032846  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libmono-android.release.so (offset 0xa16000) (Java_mono_android_Runtime_initInternal+86) (BuildId: 10717b29f55fb71204c9a80db52d4ca396c33c61)
      #11 pc 0000000000391a4b  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+219) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #12 pc 000000000036f4ff  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+2319) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #13 pc 0000000000922ec2  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/oat/x86_64/base.vdex (mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication+430)
      #14 pc 000000000036ec28  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+56) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #15 pc 000000000092302a  /data/app/~~B2U4Ry8Cqlf1TUgg2o-lYg==/com.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb-w2RlqfA40Z6M3aKZ9Alz0g==/oat/x86_64/base.vdex (mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo+82)
      #16 pc 0000000000338ea9  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider+1529) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #17 pc 0000000000338729  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders+265) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #18 pc 00000000003305a3  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication+5619) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #19 pc 0000000000324144  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+7364) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #20 pc 00000000005c4212  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+178) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #21 pc 00000000005c787e  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+1022) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #22 pc 00000000005c73b1  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+481) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #23 pc 000000000033b3fc  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+1628) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #24 pc 0000000000378826  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #25 pc 00000000003c538f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+255) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #26 pc 00000000007f0794  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1476) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #27 pc 000000000075a347  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*) (.__uniq.165753521025965369065708152063621506277)+39) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #28 pc 00000000000a3ac0  /system/framework/x86_64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+128) (BuildId: 5e29cbaed3df96b4a8070ab08ee6fe476e8b2f68)
      #29 pc 00000000007e5bd9  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+137) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #30 pc 00000000007efd78  /system/framework/x86_64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2872) (BuildId: 27e8a19f3910808b19cb4121f7461582352d3dc2)
      #31 pc 0000000000378826  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+806) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #32 pc 00000000003c538f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+255) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #33 pc 00000000007f123f  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, __va_list_tag*)+399) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #34 pc 00000000006a7e9c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+668) (BuildId: 7bb8b7e51aa2973cf22167cc6c483bef)
      #35 pc 00000000000de888  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+136) (BuildId: 140296c7da6bfd8e3c406c87d6aeb4e4)
      #36 pc 00000000000eb330  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+896) (BuildId: 140296c7da6bfd8e3c406c87d6aeb4e4)
      #37 pc 0000000000002fa6  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1622) (BuildId: f11cda2b6bb6bff1e502077a2f3e6cf7)
      #38 pc 00000000000529ef  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+95) (BuildId: fa337969c798946280caa45e2d71a2e7)
```

Comment: Hi @Dejan! Are you able to include the log output in your post? I think that would be a good idea.

Comment: @karllindmark now I realize that the log has 283 lines, is that too much to post it here?

Comment: Did you mean this only appear in release mode? Did you try the release version on different devices?

Comment: Yes, my client also experienced the same thing. We are now in the process of moving the whole project to .Net 8 and for the moment it is working (though not all code is upgraded)